# standard deviation of a sample

Tags: statistics

If a sample of size $30$ has standard deviation $8$, then a sample of size $120$ from the same distribution has a standard deviation?

I figured to use $npq = 64$ when $n = 30$, then plug in $n = 120$. But it just feels a bit off as it didn't say what kind of distribution this is. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is this question from? I get the feeling that we are missing some information or that the question has not been transcribed fully.

Comment: The question should say that the "sample standard deviation" is 8, not that the "standard deviation" is 8. We don't know what the sample standard deviation of a sample of size 120 will be equal to, because the sample standard deviation is a random variable. Its value is random, and depends on the sample values that we deserve.

Comment: sorry to reply back not in time. Yes, it is the sample standard deviation 8. But even with this correction, we still cannot get the answer,then?

Comment: I think the question does not seem to make sense. If you post the exact question word for word, or if you post an image of the question, it might help.

Answer (score 1):

For an IID sample of size $n$ drawn from a population with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ the following is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$:
$$ S_n^2 = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\bar{X}_n)^2}{n-1}.$$

Sample standard deviation is something like $\sqrt{S_n^2\frac{n-1}{n}}$. This will be a biased estimator of $\sigma$ with the bias inversely proportional to the sample size and directly proportional to population kurtosis. If the population kurtosis is very high then not only will the bias be high but also $S_{30}$ will have a huge sampling uncertainty and one will not be able to say much about $S_{120}$ from the knowledge of *one* draw from $S_{30}$. But if the population kurtosis is something like 3 and the distribution is symmetric then both $S_{30}$ and $S_{120}$ will be close to $\sigma$ and so 8 would be a reasonable ballpark guess for $S_{120}$.